# Yii: Fixtures And Setup() In Unit Test

Tags: php, yii, phpunit, fixtures

I hope someone can help me. I installed and tried to use phpunit. It Works well but now i tried to use fixtures and the setUp method and it doesn't work.

```
class RightGroupTest extends CDbTestCase {

    public $fixtures = array(
            'rights' => 'Right',
            'groups' => 'RightGroup',
    );

    public function setUp() {
            $group = new RightGroup($this->groups['group1']);
}
```

If I execute the test above I get an error message:

Exception: Unknown property 'groups' for class 'RightGroupTest'.

But if I execute this

```
class RightGroupTest extends CDbTestCase {

    public $fixtures = array(
            'rights' => 'Right',
            'groups' => 'RightGroup',
    );

    public function testIndex234() {

            $group = new RightGroup($this->groups['group1']);
}
```

everything works.

And a second question:

I have a many to many relationship. For example I can create groups and each group has several rights. Is there a way to create a group with several right objects in a fixture?
I already tried soomething like this

```
return array(
    'group1'=>array(
        'title'=>'Admin',
        'created'=>'2013-05-30',
        'updated'=>'2013-05-30',
        'rights' => array(
            $this->getRecord('right', 'right1'),
            $this->getRecord('right', 'right2'),
            $this->getRecord('right', 'right3'),
        ),
    ),
    'group2'=>array(
        'title'=>'User',
        'created'=>'2013-05-30',
        'updated'=>'2013-05-30',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixtures are loaded in `CDbTestCase` in the `setUp()` method. So if you want to override this method you should call the parent first:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    // use fixtures here
}
```

As for your second question: No, you have to create a separate fixture file for every table. The fixture system can't manage related records.

Answer (score 0):

Michael already answered your question. Additionally, note that to create a Model object, instead of using:

```
$group = new RightGroup($this->groups['group1']);
```

you can use:

```
$group = $this->groups('group1');
```

Notice the round brackets instead of the square brackets.